# Are the later rooms strictly better than the earlier ones?

Tags: fallout-shelter

At the later stages of the game, you unlock "advanced" rooms that have the same base functionality as earlier ones. I'm referring to the *Nuclear Reactor*, *Garden*, *Water Purification Plant* and *Nuka Cola Bottler*, that replace the functionality of the *Power Generator*, *Diner*, *Water Treatment Plant*.

At first glance, it seems like a good idea to (eventually) replace all your old production rooms with the new ones, once unlocked.

Are these advanced rooms **strictly** better than the earlier ones? If not, what are the downsides?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, however they cost more caps.

All of the later rooms give you greater resource/dweller, as well as greater storage/room, but at a far greater cap cost.

The Nuclear Reactor, Water Purification Plant, and Garden are all more efficient than their base equivalents, and the Nuka Cola Plant is more efficient still (but far far more expensive again).

Comment: The Nuclear Reactor also has the benefit of having vastly superior storage capabilities. This led me to believe the Purification Plant and Garden had it too, but that's not the case. They have larger storage, yes, but not as huge as the Reactor.

Comment: @Nolonar The reactor has 4x storage and a moderate production upgrade. The upgraded food/water don't have any more storage than their early-game counterparts, but the Nuka Cola bottler adds its [same-size] storage to both resources.

Comment: As an extra point, are we certain production times don't increase with higher level buildings?

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing out Gardens vs Diners, and they have equal capacity, 55 production maxed out compared to 40, but takes approx. 1.5x as long to produce it. To me, that's clearly not worth it. I'd rather have the faster production so my Mr Handy can collect it more regularly. That and 40 x 1.5 = 60, so 55 feels very tight for such an expensive upgrade. Waste of money...